# How is an independent variable turned into a dependent variable from an exact differential?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I didn't know how to title this exactly.. But I'll try to explain.

The following is an exact differential of a function $ f(x,y)$

$ df = (\frac {\partial f}{ \partial x})_y dx + (\frac { \partial f}{ \partial y})_x dy$

Where $f$ is a function in 2 independent variables $x$ and $y$

Now this is where I don't know what's going on, I can mathematically arrive at the correct result but I don't quite understand what it means:

If we consider the level curve of the function $f(x,y) = c$

Then the total differential $df = 0$

Then we get that $(\frac { \partial f}{ \partial x})_y dx = - (\frac { \partial f}{ \partial y})_x dy$

Dividing by the differential $dx$ , holding $f$ constant, then:

$ (\frac { \partial y} { \partial x})_f = \frac {(\frac { \partial f}{ \partial x})_y}{-(\frac { \partial f}{ \partial y})_x}$

We have just constructed an equation that relates $y$ to $x$ and its derivative $\frac {dy}{dx}$  , $y$ just became a dependent variable on $x$

What is happening exactly, geometrically, or however you can put it intuitively? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of the implicit function theorem. If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is non-zero, you can locally solve $f(x,y) = c$ for $y$, i.e. locally there is a differentiable function $g$ such that $f(x,g(x)) = c$. The derivative of $g$ is then exactly what you derived. Intuitively it is just an equation $f(x,y) = c$ and you are trying to solve it for $y$. Then $y$ becomes a function of $x$.